# How to use Vue prop as variable in method?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I'm fairly new to Vue and am having a tough time grasping all of the concepts. I am currently building a Laravel application and am using Vue to supplement some views.  What I am trying to do is a pretty simple call to my backend API with the help of a prop set up with the Vue component (Laravel Nova card).

I have an `account_id` that I am able to access through a prop like so:

```
resource.fields[3].value
```

I am then trying to make a call to the api and save data relevant to the account

```
data() {
    return {
        account: {
            name: '',
            location: '',
            type: ''
        }
    };
},

methods: {
    getAccount() {
        let vm = this;
        var account_id = vm.resource.fields[3].value;
        page_url = page_url || '/api/accounts/${account_id}';
        fetch(page_url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.account = res.data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

And then render it in my view:

```
<h1>{{ account.name }}</h1>
<p>{{ account.location }}</p>
<p>{{ account.type }}</p>
```

All of my endpoints are correct - when I visit `app.dev/api/accounts/{id}` I get a JSON array with all of my fields. But, I see no data in my views when I try to render it.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Should `this.account = res.data;` instead be `vm.account = res.data;` to set the value on your component?

Comment: @Peter shouldn't matter since OP is using arrow functions

Comment: You have `app.dev/api/accounts/{id}` and `/api/accounts/${account_id}`. which one should it be? Also where is the `props` defined?

Comment: **Always** check your browser console first for errors. Also check the _Network_ tab where you should be able to see any AJAX requests. Do you see the request being made? If so, what is the response (including the actual response data)

Comment: @Phil Of course! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first you need to check the request to the server what is the URL has been requested.

So, I think in here `page_url = page_url || '/api/accounts/${account_id}';` you should using the backticks (`) like this `` page_url = page_url || `/api/accounts/${account_id}`; ``

If all of these not working for you. I think you can pass it via `props`

```
data() {
    return {
        account: {
            name: '',
            location: '',
            type: ''
        }
    };
},
props: ['account_id'],
methods: {
    getAccount() {
        let vm = this;
        var account_id = vm.resource.fields[3].value;
        page_url = page_url || `/api/accounts/${this.account_id}`;
        fetch(page_url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.account = res.data;
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

In the caller component, using v-bind="account_id" to `prop` to this component.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Aha, great catch about the backticks. Nice!

Comment: Yes, it was the backticks! Thank you